# Does executeUpdate method run in the if-statment condition?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Using the Statement.executeUpdate(String sql) method in the IF condition, does it actually execute the SQL on the database?

For example:

```
void update(Statement stmt){
  String sql = "UPDATE room SET chairs=2 WHERE id=1";
  if (stmt.executeUpdate(sql) != 1) throw Exception;
  sql = "SELECT name FROM room WHERE id=1";
  result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
}
```

So does the executeUpdate(sql) part actually run and update the database or does it just check the condition in the IF-statement without updating anything?

Comment: How could the `executeUpdate` method's return value be possibly compared to `1` without running it?

Comment: I just wasn't sure if it is actually run such that the data in the database is updated, or just run to determine the return value without updating the actual data (executeUpdate just returns 0 or the number of rows affected right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (stmt.executeUpdate(sql) != 1)
```

This executes the body of the if block if the expression `stmt.executeUpdate(sql) != 1` is true. So Java must evaluate this expression.

This expression compares the value **returned** by `stmt.executeUpdate(sql)` with -1. To be able to know the value returned by `stmt.executeUpdate(sql)`, it must execute the method.

So yes, this executes the method.

Comment: I just wasn't sure if it is actually run such that the data in the database is updated, or just run to determine the return value without updating the actual data.